# Home network (Vista) access IIS localhost from another computer

Tags: windows-vista, networking, iis, localhost

I have two computers on a home network. One is a development machine, testing sites on IIS (http:// myclientsite/). My other computer (Laptop) is connected through a wireless – it can access shared folders just fine.

How do I allow Laptop to access the site (http:// myclientsite/) located on the development machine?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to modife your host file in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc and add an entry that maps the IP of the vista machine to myclientsite.

Comment: that did the trick